# How to use the C64x+ GMPY instruction to compute a CRC32?

Tags: crc32, ti-dsp

How can I use the Galois Field Multiply (GMPY) instruction featured in TI C64x+ DSPs to efficiently compute a CRC32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texas Instruments have a code-sample.

See the last pages of this presentation: http://piraten.in/gy0

Comment: That actually worked, after I reversed the order of the _gmpy statements.